# Adding a Condition to match the ID with JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba, url

[image]

I am trying to create a two conditions in `Col"B"` and `Col"L"` if matches then take the `ID Number` from `Col"P"` and get the result in `JSON`.

JSON appear like this:

```json
     {"id":16,"sku":"4926","productName":"Diforda","upc":"test",
      "condition":"test","uniqueID":1234,"logsCey":3,
      "Processing":true,"addedDateTime":"2021-06-22T04:07:35.15",
      "softDelete":false,"newLogno":776655}
```

After that code will find in JSON where `Processing = True` then take the `newLogno` from JSON and paste that in `Col"A"` against same `Row` if it is `False` then repeat the same process for `2nd ID Number from Col"P"`.

If someone can please share a solution. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```vb
Sub Testing()

Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strUrl As String
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strResponse As String
Dim idno As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Sheet4
    
    

    LRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For r = LRow To 2 Step -1
    idno = ws.Cells(r, "P").Value
                If ws.Cells(r, "B") <> "" And ws.Cells(r, "L") = "Tenu" Then

                Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                strUrl = "URL" & idno
    End If

    blnAsync = True

With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .send

                While objRequest.readyState <> 4
                    DoEvents
                Wend
                
    strResponse = .ResponseText
        
End With
Next

strResponse = ws.Cells(r, "A")

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with your code?  You seem to be missing an `End If` and you can't do this `strUrl = "URL" & idno` since `idno` is a 2-D array and not a string.

Comment: The problem is i am stuck on how to create a loop which will repeat the same process. In the URL there is last value of id so i created `idno` this string. ITs even not working for single ID.

Comment: Try with `strUrl = "URL" & idno(r, 1)` or `strUrl = ws.Cells(r, "P").Value`

Comment: Tried the first one and receiving an error `Compile Error: Expected Array` on `idno(r, 1)`

Comment: `idno` should be a 2D array if LRow is >1 (which it should be, based on your screenshot)  `idno` should be declared as Variant.

Comment: Now its running since your last comment, there are 100K rows with data but only two rows met the condition but nothing is happening.

Comment: You will need to do some debugging.  Not much I can do without a URL or test data...

Comment: Forget the 100k rows and first just focus on getting one row to work.

Comment: Yea first it has to work for single row.

Comment: `strResponse = ws.Cells(r, "A")` should be  `ws.Cells(r, "A") = strResponse `

Comment: Yeah i tried same before but do not have `ColA` ID `"Processing":true`  if it is true then copy last Id in json

Comment: For parsing JSON typically people here recommend this:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: I would humbly request you to please share a solution @Tim Williams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Sub Testing()

    Const blnAsync As Boolean = True

    Dim strUrl As String, strResponse As String, idno As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LRow As Long, r As Long
    Dim JSON As Object, n As Long

    Set ws = Sheet4
    LRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
    For r = 2 To LRow        
        If ws.Cells(r, "B") <> "" And ws.Cells(r, "L") = "Tenu" Then

            idno = ws.Cells(r, "P").Value
            strUrl = "URL" & idno
       
            With objRequest
                .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
                .send
                While .readyState <> 4
                    DoEvents
                Wend
                strResponse = .ResponseText
            End With

            Set JSON = ParseJson(strResponse)
            If JSON("Processing") = True Then
                ws.Cells(r, "A").Value = JSON("newLogno")
                n = n + 1
            End If
            
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox n & " records found", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @CDP1802 for making it accurate. but receiving an error that is [error](https://ibb.co/NNh1XMZ) on `ParseJson`

Comment: @arham Have you imported the JsonConverter.bas module

Comment: No i do no know about this how to import it can you please share.

Comment: I added thank you very much @CDP1802 but when i run the code first time it gives this error https://ibb.co/QdBrQFj when run second time it works. How to fix this thing?

Comment: @Arhem I guess the response isn't ready so add the `While objRequest.readyState <> 4 ; DoEvents ; Wend` in after `.send`